# Haskell why does "Num x" require "Show x"?

Tags: haskell

Recently I took a look at Haskell, using [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com).

I was messing around with type classes and wrote this quick test function:

```
foo :: (Num x) => x -> String
foo x = show x ++ "!"
```

But that produces this error:

```
test.hs:2:9:
    Could not deduce (Show x) arising from a use of `show'
    from the context (Num x)
    bound by the type signature for foo :: Num x => x -> String
    at test.hs:1:8-29
    Possible fix:
      add (Show x) to the context of
        the type signature for foo :: Num x => x -> String
```

But according to LYAH:

> To join Num, a type must already be friends with Show and Eq.

So if everything in `Num` is a subset of `Show` and `Eq`, why do I need to change the type signature to `foo :: (Num x, Show x) => x -> String` for this to work? Shouldn't it be possible to infer that a `Num` is also Show-able?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The information in LYAH is old. The [release notes for GHC 7.4.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html) say that:

> The Num class no longer has Eq or Show superclasses.

You will need to write,

```
foo :: (Num x, Show x) => x -> String
```

(In fact, the `foo` you wrote doesn't require `Num x`, so you can omit that to avoid an unnecessary constraint.)

Comment: So what subclasses of `Num` _don't_ have `Eq` or `Show` anymore? I don't see any listings of what gained those (Or why it was changed at all, actually.)

Comment: It used to be `class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where {...}`, now it's just `class Num a where {...}`. There was no need to have `Eq` and `Show` as a superclass: a `Num` instance does not imply an instance of either of those classes (like `Ord` implies `Eq`), nor does it depend on them (`Num` has no laws, and the default definitions for its 'methods' don't refer to `Eq` or `Show`). I think that's why `Num` became a stand-alone class. Less requirements means that the class allows for more instances, such as `Num b => Num (a -> b)`.

Comment: It's important to note that this is a GHC change; the Haskell standard still demands `Show` and `Eq` superclasses. In the strict sense, this makes GHC a non-Haskell-compliant compiler; however, this change will most likely make its way into the next standard anyway, much like soon `Applicative` will be a superclass of `Monad`.

Answer (score 4):

It [used to be](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aNum) that an instance of `Num` was also an instance of `Show` and `Eq` , but that's [no longer the case](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aNum).

You'll need to add a `Show` constraint as well.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell, both [98](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html) and [2010](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1270006.3) both require all instances of Num to also be instances on Show and Eq.  This is largely an accident of history.

GHC, the most popular Haskell compiler, diverges from the standard here without requiring any pragma.  This was done to allow applicative functors to be instances of Num and enjoy the benefits of overloaded syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you write:

```
(Num x) => x -> String
```

Instead of

```
(Num x) x -> String
```

And as far as I know this inheritance is at least outdated.