# Haskell, Instance, Type Constraints

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, instance

I created in Haskell a new class `Eqa`

```
class Eqa a where

   (=~) :: a -> a -> Bool

   (/~) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

and want to define `(=~)` same as `(==)` from the Prelude. So I tried

```
instance Eqa Int where            
   x=~y = x==y

   x/~y = x/=y
```

but this only works for `Int` (of course).
How do I have to change my code that this works with all numerical types?

Comment: *How do I have to change my code that this works with all numerical types?* What does "this" refer to in your sentence, exactly?

Comment: With my defined instance I am only able to compare types of Int but I want to compare all numerical Types i.e. float, Integer, ...

Comment: This isn't something you can really do. The Num typeclass doesn't provide `(==)`. You can convince GHC to accept a definition of `instance Num a => Eqa a` with the right language pragmas but it's nonsensical and in practice you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write

```
(=~) :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool
x=~y = x==y
```

If you don't actually need the code to be different for different types, why do you need a class at all?

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is to bind `a` to `Num a` or

```
instance Num a => Eqa a where            
    x=~y = x==y
    x/~y = x/=y
```

For more information, take a look at [Numeric Types subsection of Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html#typeclasses.wellknown.numeric) to understand which class is related to each numerical types.

Comment: This isn't a great solution.  First of all, it doesn't work as written: it requires `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`; plus, in modern GHCs, `Eq` is no longer a superclass of `Num`, so you need an `Eq a` constraint too.  More importantly, though, it makes defining other instances of `Eqa` rather fraught: if we add `instance Eqa () where { _ =~ _ = True ; _ /~ _ = False }`, then `() =~ ()` gives us an "Overlapping instances" error, because `()` *could* have a `Num` instance!

Comment: @AntalS-Z Do you happen to know when (i.e., for which version of GHC) `Eq` ceased to be a superclass of `Num`?

Comment: @Jubobs: Since GHC 7.4.1.  Here are [the GHC 7.4.1 release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html), which says "The `Num` class no longer has `Eq` or `Show` superclasses"; compare [the GHC 7.2.1 release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html), which say nothing of the sort.  This is from [Ben James's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19327850/237428) to [exactly this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19327792/237428).